# PyQt5: Avoid reducing multiple spaces in QLabel / QPlainTextEdit

Tags: pyqt5, formatting, whitespace, qlabel, qplaintextedit

In PyQt5, both QLabel and QPlainTextEdit Widgets appear to shrink multiple whitespaces in to one. Say if I set the label text to: `"abc    abc    abc"`, text shown is `"abc abc abc"`.

Apparently, this is happening because of the default html formatting these widgets are using.

Is there a way to set these widgets to show the original text with multiple spaces keeping the original formatting ?

Edit:

QLabel- I was able to get this sorted by introducing `<pre>` tags. Can anyone help with the QPlainTextEdit ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `QPlainTextEdit` class does not reduce multiple whitespace, and it does not support html at all (as is suggested by the name). The `QLabel` class also does not reduce multiple whitespace unless you explicitly include html tags (and if you can't avoid that, you can simply use `<pre>` tags where necessary).

However, I suspect you may be using a variable-width font that has relatively narrow space characters, so the apparent whitespace reduction is actually illusory. If you use a fixed-width font instead, the illusion should disappear.